# List does not align horizontal even with correct style

Tags: html, css, navigation

Pretty simple what I am trying to accomplish.

I am trying to recreate this

http://www.adtile.me/fixed-nav/

However the navigation is not cooperating with me in horizontal direction.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header class="shadow">
        <img id="logo"src="assets/images/logo white.png" width="305" height="78"/>   
            <nav class="nav-collapse">
                <ul id="horizontal">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#horizontal {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

[Demo](http://beta2.monikanormandphoto.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `inline` on the list-items, not the parent `ul`:

```
#horizontal li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/twn66yvg/)

Comment: Thanks! easy solution.

Comment: @squid267 no problem. Glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved when you get a chance?

Comment: Done! Sorry about delay